# What do you call it when A cannot alter B above A?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, technical

There's only one true example I can give without going off the idea and this example is quite "techy", so I'm sorry for those who possibly won't understand the principle. I'm certainly not being ignorant, I just cannot think of any other as good example as this one.

There's a virtualization program called Virtual Box, which creates a virtual, emulated environment in which you can run another operating system inside your main operating system. The whole environment is completely emulated, therefore the system inside it (called the guest system) has no access to your main system and cannot alter it. Thus, this guest system cannot operate any faster than the main system, cannot outperform it in any way. What is this called? When a sub-category item (child) cannot "understand/outperform" its group parent?

Comment: Gödel's incompleteness theorem? :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say that the child category is *bounded by* the parent category. This implies that the limits of the parent are imposed onto the child.

Comment: Thinking more clearly I realise you're right - both in this answer, and in pointing out that discussion about the relative performance of host/sandboxed systems goes beyond what is relevant here. That was only OP's example, and your *bounded* applies in the general case, so I'm deleting my answer and upvoting yours.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks -- I really liked the explanation you had for "sandboxed", though.

Answer (score 5):

Specifically for your example, the inner system is [*sandboxed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29) – a technical term which has appeared to describe a program which is allowed to play in its own little pool of resources, but has no access outside of that